# Writing a 1d integral as a 2d integral

Tags: integration

Suppose I am trying to calculate the following integral

$$I= \int_D f(x)dx $$
where $D$ is the domain of integration.
I then define a function $g(x,y) = f(x+y)$. How can I then write $I$ as a double integral of $g(x,y)$ over $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Have you made any attempts thus far? If so, what; if not, try!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? It is possible that for particular $f$ and $D$ you can find a solution, but in general, no.